# Bioplastic from starch

Tags: biochemistry, carbohydrates

I am doing research in bioplastic from starch. I have tried many quantities and concentrations of starch, vinegar and glycerol at different temperatures. But I am unable to get a certain result of the desired flexibility. I actually want to make bioplastic jewelry from it but either the products are too hard or not enough hard. I also tried putting agar, but the problem of contamination is seen. Can anyone suggest a suitable solution to the problem I am encountering?

Comment: Try starch, glycerol and water ! No vinegar.

Comment: tried that as well. Didnt work